# How to setup model that has a many to many relationship to both itself and another model and allow sorting?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a **Collections** table, a **Components** table, and a pivot table for a many-to-many relationship between Collections and Components.  This lets me create 'Collections' of 'components'.  Im using [rutorika-sortable](https://github.com/boxfrommars/rutorika-sortable) to enable sorting of the components.

The issue is that I also want the possibility for a Collection to be related to another Collection.  I tried a 'Collection-Collection' pivot table, and the problem I ran into was I could no longer figure out how to deal with sorting.  For example, I want  **Component A**, **Collection B** and **Component B** to belong to **Collection A** and be displayed in that order when viewing **Collection A**.  Sorting no longer works because the order columns in the two pivots are independent of each other.

Im thinking I need some sort of polymorhpic relationship, but im not sure what the best way to go about this would be. How can I achieve the results I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this is the best approach, but to resolve this I added a **one-to-one** relationship where **collections** hasOne **component** in addition to the existing **many-to-many** relationship.

Now, a component that has its **collection_id** field filled in will act as a sort of alias to that collection. Then when I go through all the components linked to a collection, I can check if they are linked to another collection or not and act accordingly.

The main downside is that from now on, before a component and collection can be linked via **many-to-many** I need to check to make sure they arent already related on the **one-to-one**, or vice versa, to prevent recursion.